# Are the alleles that code for the same phenotype all the same exact sequence?

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics, dna-sequencing, molecular-evolution

The idea that you can be homozygous for a gene means that there are limited options or alleles , correct ?

My question is, if the mom has the allele b which codes for a blue eye, and the dad has an allele which codes for a blue eye too, are these alleles the exact same ? Do they have the same nucleotide sequence ?

This is probably a basic question but no matter how I phrase it, I can't seem to get an answer off of google.

Comment: Most educational texts ignore the nucleotide variations and only look at the gross effect of the gene, and the gene interactions. Like @Cell says, they only care if the gene works or  not. They dont care about the millions of variations that may cause the gene to not work.

Answer (score 1):

No the same phenotypes do not mean the same sequence. For example some phenotypes are associated with alleles that are caused by non-functional gene products (like proteins). But there many ways to alter a gene to produce a non-functional protein.